# TNY264 - hisses when isn't load significantly

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply

Recently I designed a power supply based on **TNY264** datasheet schematic and tested it.

[image: Schema]

It works perfectly but at small loads the TNY generates a loud hissing sound.

Only after load of about 100-120mA does the hiss fall to an acceptable level.

At first I thought it is the transformer generating the "hiss". But it is in fact dedicated for this model.

If someone has more experience than me, please tell me what can I change to need a smaller load works correctly without hissing.

Thanks for every help.

Comment: discontinuous mode, at low load currents

Answer (score 2):

it's called "burp mode" and it's normal.

the normally ultrasonic noise of the power-supply becomes audible when the power-supply stops an restarts several times per second because the load is too light to have it run continuously,

Usually it's one of the magnetic parts making the noise, but some capacitors can also act as transducers.

Comment: It's normal for all SMPS switches? Previously performing a power supply on LNK362 and behaved well even no load without "burp mode".